# How to access form in child component from parent component in angular 6?

Tags: forms, angular6, parent-child

My problem is I have a parent component and many child components to my parent component.Parent Component don't have any form and child components have forms.All the child components are sharing the same route of parent component and child component don't have any router-link to uniquely identify.So task is to display pop-up when form is dirty and user is navigating away from that page.So I implemented can-deactivate guard.So in "app.module.ts" How can I give can-deactivate to child components(bcz child components don't have any router-path).
How can I achieve this?

Could someone please help me with this?Struggling from past two days :(
Any other solution is also fine
Hugeee thanx in advance

can-deactivate-guard.ts:

```
import {ComponentCanDeactivate} from './component-can-deactivate';

@Injectable()
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<ComponentCanDeactivate> {
  canDeactivate(component: ComponentCanDeactivate): boolean {

    if(!component.canDeactivate()){
        if (confirm("You have unsaved changes! If you leave, your changes will be lost.")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

component-can-deactivate.ts:

```
export abstract class ComponentCanDeactivate {
 abstract  canDeactivate(): boolean;
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
    unloadNotification($event: any) {
        if (!this.canDeactivate()) {
            $event.returnValue =true;
        }
    }
}
```

form-can-deactivate.ts:

```
export abstract class FormCanDeactivate extends ComponentCanDeactivate{

 abstract get form():NgForm;

 canDeactivate():boolean{
      return this.form.submitted || !this.form.dirty
  }
}
```

parent component.html:No forms in ParentComponent.html

```
<child1>some actions</child1>
<child2>some actions</child2>
```

and so on
child1.component.html:

```
<form #form="ngForm">some fields</form>
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
routes={path:':parent/somepath',component:ParentComponent,canDeactivate:[CanDeactivateGuard]}
```

Comment: If you add some example of your code. It will be so easy to help you. Example  on StackBliz

Comment: Ok,I can give you sample code

Comment: You can edit your post to best view.Dont try to writte code in comments

Answer (score 0):

if you are loading a different `component` inside a container without changing the urls and you need to check the forms state whether its **dirty** or not before navigating, so you can get this on `ngOnDestroy()`. This event fire once you move away from active component.

if you need to handle browsers events like back/refresh/close button you need to add `@HostListener` decorator